# Jquery form submit in struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a struts form as

```
    <s:form id="bw-form" name="bwform" action="submitBwForm">
    .
    .
    .
    <Div align="center"><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="uponSave()"></Div>
    <Div id="msg" align="center"></Div>
    </s:form>
```

I have this in my struts.xml:

```
<action name="submitBwForm" class="com.att.tqt.action.BWAction" method="submitFormToDb">
        <result name="success">DataPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In my js file I have,

```
function uponSave(){    
alert("before submit");
$("#msg").html("<Font color='red'>Successfully Added</Font>");
$("#msg").show();   
$("#bw-form").submit();
}
```

In my action class:

```
public class BWAction extends ActionSupport {
    public String submitFormToDb(){
        System.out.println("in action");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

When I click on the save button, I do not see the action. I just get the alert. 
When i use

```
document.bwform.action = "submitBwForm!submitFormToDb";
document.bwform.submit();
```

instead of `$("#bw-form").submit();`
I am able to see the sysout, "in action" getting printed on the console and the page rightly redirects to DataPage.jsp

What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your JSP page?

Comment: Unrelated, but what's the code *after* the submit supposed to do? You've submitted the form already.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes. I did.

Comment: @Prasanna: Any errors in console?

Comment: @AleksandrM No, I dont see any errors.